# Python flask json schema validation

Tags: python, flask

I am using the flask framework in my new project. It would get JSON data from the post and send a JSON response. So, I need to validate my JSON request.

I have seen couple of libraries. But those libraries are not working as expected. Finally, I have decided to go with a `flask-jsonschema-validator`. It is working fine with a single JSON object. If the request object has a nested object, it is not working.

For example:

```
from flask_jsonschema_validator import JSONSchemaValidator
JSONSchemaValidator(app=app, root="schemas")
```

This is my initialization of the validator:

```
# If any error occurred in the request.
@app.errorhandler(jsonschema.ValidationError)
def json_validation_error(e):
    return json_response("error", str(e), {})
```

This is my error handler

```
@app.validate('model', 'save')
def save_model():
```

This is my implementation:

```
{
  "save": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "workspace": {"type": "object"},
      "name": {"type": "string"},
      "description": {"type": "string"},
      "uri": {"type": "string"},
      "type": {
         "name": {"type": "string"},
      }
    },
    "required": [ "workspace", "name", "description", "uri", "type"]
  }
}
```

This is my `model.json` file. It is validating the request except for the "type". How to apply validation for JSON request with nested object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[flask-expects-json](https://pypi.org/project/flask-expects-json/) package checks variables types on nested objects.

It work as a decorator on your route.

```
SCHEMA = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "workspace": {"type": "object"},
      "name": {"type": "string"},
      "description": {"type": "string"},
      "uri": {"type": "string"},
      "type": {
         "type": "object",
         "properties": {
              "name": {"type": "string"},
         }
      }
    },
    "required": ["workspace", "name", "description", "uri", "type"]
}

@expects_json(SCHEMA)
def my_route(self, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Already I have tried like this. It's working. But validation not working in type object. Should I give in required section as "type.name". But this also not working

Comment: I've uploaded my answer. I didn't correctly update the json schema. When you have a variable of type "object", you have to specify it. and you  then you can define it's `properties`.

Comment: Thank you. It's working fine. How do we send an error message as a JSON format? Currently, It shows HTML format

Comment: The simplest and best way. Is to implement a custom error. Here is an example : https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/apierrors/

Comment: "required": ["name", "description", "type.name"].Should I give like this to validate the type.name

Comment: It should validate all properties of the schema, including  `type.name`. `required` just force you to pass some arguments.

Comment: ["name", "description", "type.name"]. This is not validating "type.name". Do I need to add anything else?

Comment: Maybe adding a `required` property in the `type` object : `"type": {
         "type": "object",
         "properties": {
              "name": {"type": "string"},
         },"required": ["name"]
      }`

Answer (score 0):

If the validation of complex nested objects, I would recommend an alternative tool to JSONSchema. I can replicate your schema validation in [GoodJSON](https://github.com/namoshizun/goodjson) like below. As you can see, formulating a validation schema is just composing a bunch of self-contained validator functions that can be applied to objects, lists and primitive values.

```python
from goodjson.validators import is_dict, is_string, is_uri, foreach_key


validate_fun = foreach_key(
    save=[foreach_key(
        workspace=[is_dict],
        name=[is_string],
        description=[is_string],
        uri=[is_uri],
        type=[foreach_key(
            name=[is_string]
        )]
    )]
)

validate_fun(YOUR_JSON_DATA_OBJECT)
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of GoodJSON.